# How to get object of one of the abstract class implementations passed in a json object

Tags: java, spring, jackson, abstract-class, json-deserialization

I have a spring project wherein I have an abstract class Person as following

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@Type(value=Employee.class, name="employee"), @Type(value = Driver.class, name = "driver")}) 
public abstract class Person {

}
```

I have 2 implementations of this Person class, Employee and Driver as following

```
@JsonTypeName("employee")
public class Employee extends Person {

 private int field1;
 private int field2;
 
 //some getters and setters
 
}

@JsonTypeName("driver")
public class Driver extends Person {

 private int field3;
 private int field4;
 private int field5;
 
 //some getters and setters
 
}
```

The Person object is contained in Company class as follows

```
public class Company {

 private String name;
 private int id;
 private Person person;// this is the object
 private int people;


}
```

Now, I receive the request in a json format and one of the fields is this person object as follows:

```
{
 "name": "some name",
 "id": 123,
 "person":{
    "type": "employee"
    "field1":"some field1 value",
    "field2":"some field2 value"
 },
 "people": 100
 
}
```

The thing is, the person can be either of driver or employee type. The field "type"(not present as a variable) is passed in json and the corresponding object is instantiated. However I am unable to get the hold of the instantiated object as the instantiation happens on runtime and I am not able to tell in the code which class was instantiated. And hence can't call the getters of the appropriate object(employee or driver).

Is there a way I can get the hold of the instantiated object so that I can do whatever I want with the fields of the object(field1 and field2 in case of employee and field3, field4 and field5 in case of driver), say `company.getPerson().getField1();`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getField1()` is a method of `Employee` and not of any `Person`, then no you can't do `getPerson().getField1()`.

And that's logic. If you're invoking `getField1()` on a `Person`, then it means that you know that this `Person` is an `Employee` and not a `Driver`.

So, you should simply separate the code handling a `Employee` from the one handling a `Driver`:

```
Person person = company.getPerson();
if (person instanceof Employee) {
    Employee employee = (Employee) person;
    employee.getField1();
    //...
} else if (person instanceof Driver) {
    Driver driver = (Driver) person;
    driver.getField3();
    //...
}
```